# Powershell: Using .Split on Filename functioning differently based on filename capitalization

Tags: powershell, filenames, string-manipulation

I have a bunch of image files that accidentally got renamed with a "doubled" file extension (e.g. `IMG_1469.jpg.jpg`). I wrote a script to remove the extra file extension, but for some reason, it functions differently based on whether the file extension is in all caps or all lowercase. It functions as intended if the extension is lowercase.

Given two files in the same folder with the following filenames:

```
$FileA = IMG_1468.JPG.JPG
$FileB = IMG_1469.jpg.jpg
```

```
$file = Get-ChildItem -Path "\\UNC\Path\To\File" | Where-Object -Property Name -EQ $FileA
If (($file.BaseName).Length -GT 3) {
        $extCheck = ($file.BaseName).Substring(($file.BaseName).Length - 4,4)
        Write-Host "extCheck =" $extCheck
        If ($file.Extension -EQ $extCheck) {
            $oldName = $file.Name
            Write-Host "oldName =" $oldName
            Write-Host "File.Extension =" $file.Extension
            $newName = ($oldName).Split($extCheck)[0]+$file.Extension
            Write-Host "newName =" $newName
            $file | Rename-Item -NewName { $newName }
        }
}
```

Output using $FileA:

```
extCheck = .JPG
oldName = IMG_1468.JPG.JPG
File.Extension = .JPG
newName = IM.JPG

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item: \UNC\Path\To\File\IMG_1468.JPG.JPG 
Destination: \\UNC\Path\To\File\IMG.JPG".
```

Output using $FileB:

```
extCheck = .jpg
oldName = IMG_1469.jpg.jpg
File.Extension = .jpg
newName = IMG_1469.jpg

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item: \UNC\Path\To\File\IMG_1469.jpg.jpg 
Destination: \\UNC\Path\To\File\IMG_1469.jpg".
```

Anyone have any idea why .Split is removing everything from the base name after "IM" instead of just removing `.JPG` like it does when the extra extension is `.jpg`?

Comment: i don't know why that happens ... but i do know that your are doing things in a very delicate, fragile way. this >>> `$FileA.BaseName -replace $FileA.Extension, ''` <<< will convert this >>> `'IMG_1468.JPG.JPG'` <<< to this >>> `'IMG_1468'` <<< ///// after that, you can simply add the .Extension back onto the remaining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @Lee_Daily

> `$FileA.BaseName -replace $FileA.Extension, ''` 
> will convert this >>> `'IMG_1468.JPG.JPG'`<<<
> to this >>> `'IMG_1468'` <<<
> after that, you can simply add the .Extension back onto the remaining

I still have no idea why .Split was acting the way it was, but rewriting the $newName definition as advised by @Lee_Daily seems to be agnostic to capitalization (thus solving my root problem):

```
        $newBaseName = $file.BaseName -replace $file.Extension
        $newName = $newBaseName+$file.Extension
        Write-Host "newName =" $newName
        $file | Rename-Item -NewName { $newName } -WhatIf
```

This now gives me the output I was looking for even when the input is the capitalized value of $FileA:

```
extCheck = .JPG
oldName = IMG_1468.JPG.JPG
File.Extension = .JPG
newName = IMG_1468.JPG

What if: Performing the operation "Rename File" on target 
"Item: \UNC\Path\To\File\IMG_1468.JPG.JPG 
Destination: \\UNC\Path\To\File\IMG_1468.JPG".
```

Comment: neatly done! ... and i, too, have no idea what the `.Split()` problem really is. [*grin*]